Flutter Web TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined after upgrading to 3.24.0
I recently upgraded my Flutter project to version 3.24.0 and started encountering the error

"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined" on the web platform.
This error didn't occur in previous versions.

I've tried the following solutions without success:

flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub cache repair
Downgrading the Dart SDK version in pubspec.yaml to   sdk: '>=3.3.0 <4.0.0'
I'm running out of ideas and would appreciate any help.



You use Lottie in your code, check it, what is it? it's a package or something?

Yes it's a package ,but the problem is not in package , undefined (reading X) X change in every run @gopelkujo
